# Compare multiple columns in multiple sheets excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am a complete novice when it comes to excel.  I have a workbook that has 2 similar worksheets.  Worksheet 1 is my master worksheet had more data. Both worksheets has 2 columns, Request No and Time.

```
Worksheet 1
Request No.   |   Time
1234          |   27
7890          |   67

Worksheet 2
Request No.   |   Time
1234          |   27
7890          |   60
```

I want to compare worksheet 1 Request no. with worksheet 2 request no. and time column against each request no.

Thanks in advance

EDIT : I want to display the result in last column if it matches or not?[image]

Hello Tim, I have added the image, I have changed the variables and range in VlookUp formula, but it doesn't work?

Comment: What is the purpose of this comparison?

Comment: I want to display the result in last column if it matches or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `VLOOKUP` function should do the trick.  Here is a screen capture showing you how you can do this:

[image]

Enter the following formula into `C2`:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!A2:B3, 2) = B2, "yes", "no")
```

This assumes that your second worksheet contains the same layout as the screen capture for the first worksheet which I have above.  You may also have to adjust the range of the `VLOOKUP` if you more than 2 rows in your actual data set.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I have added the image, I have changed the variables and range in VlookUp formula, but it doesn't work. Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

here is a code for just try and check [chek](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/)
 when you use diffrent sheets u want remember this 
To reference a cell of a different Workbook use this pattern:

```
[<Workbook_name>]<Sheetname>!<Cell>
```

**example : [Worksheet 1]sheet1!A1**

Comment: What if the sheet name has spaces in it? :)

Comment: if your name **my** name then type like **my name!**

Comment: sheet names with spaces, and some other characters in, need to be wrapped in single quotes. `'space name'!A1`